# How can I freeze last column of a datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid. I placed a delete button column at the end of each row.
Since the datagrid containing more columns than its width, I should scroll to the end to see the delete button.
Can I freeze the last column of datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2591#issuecomment-990929620) is the my solution. You can define a class that derived from `DataGridCellsPanel` and override the `ArrangeOverride` method to calculate the arrangement of the last few columns to frozen them.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to freeze the right most column without writing your own extension on `DataGrid`.

If you're okay with it you could put the 'Delete' column on the left and freeze it with the property [`FrozenColumnCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)